# How to use Openshift Service Registry with Java Spring Boot + Ribbon

Tags: spring-boot, openshift, netflix-ribbon

How to use openshift's service Registry inside a Spring Boot application?

In the openshift's documentation about [Service Registry](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/reference_architectures/2017/html-single/spring_boot_microservices_on_red_hat_openshift_container_platform_3/#openshift), it says that:

> Ribbon can be declaratively configured to use OpenShift instead of a service registry, without any code changes.

How can I configure Ribbon to use Openshift's service registry?

Comment: Not sure exactly what technique you are thinking of, can you provide more details? A little bit of information about using DNS SRV records can be found in http://cookbook.openshift.org/services-networking-and-routing/how-can-i-discover-running-pods-using-dns-srv-records.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton Sorry, forgot to answer you! I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: No idea what those docs are suggesting. There is a REST API in OpenShift where can query about state of configuration, including finding out what pods are registered against a service. Maybe it is using that, don't know. For that to work at least, you need to grant the application access to the REST APU. Some information in http://cookbook.openshift.org/users-and-role-based-access-control/how-do-i-enable-rest-api-access-for-an-application.html But you probably still configure the application to enable it to do it.